# Android version of KYCircleMenu

Tags: java, android

How might I go about creating an Android version of the iOS KYCircleMenu project found at:

https://github.com/Kjuly/KYCircleMenu

It doesn't need to be exactly the same, but I would like to find some sort of tutorial that creates a similar effect of displaying buttons in a circle around a center image or button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not exactly what you want , but the next samples might be useful and you might be able to tweak them to your needs:

http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/radial-menu-widget/

http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/samples/Circle-Launcher

http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/arcmenu/

http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/glowpadview-lockring/

as a side note , i would recommend to avoid a circular menu , simply because when you touch the screen , it's hard to see all of the items since the finger/hand hides part of them.

Comment: @DharaShah you're welcomed. would you also like me to suggest you of other websites/apps to show demos?

Comment: ay no sir, not at the moment. Will definitely get back if incase the arc menu does not work :).. thank u

Comment: @DharaShah ok, good luck. please let me know if you've succeeded, and consider sharing your code.