# Radial popupMenu in Java (Swing)?

Tags: java, user-interface, contextmenu

After a few conversations at work, I got interested in a radial menu for a java based GUI (I mostly know about swing, so that would be my immediate preference).

Looking round, there seems to mainly be JavaScript radial menus, or ones for Android that I found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763005/android-version-of-kycirclemenu/14763607#14763607):

- [ArcMenu](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/arcmenu/)
- [GlowPadView](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/glowpadview-lockring/)

But I haven't seen any dedicated packages/libraries to do this in a 'vanilla' (i.e. not java tailored to work on Android) java.

I guess this question comes in two parts then:

- Are there any dedicated options for creating radial menus in Java?

  - Preferably using Swing
- How much of a challenge would it be to 'adapt' the android libraries to use on a desktop program?

Comment: After some more searching, I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/hoa-pie-menu/) but I've not tried it, or looked into it properly (I don't even know if it's what I'm after).

Comment: Did you ever find anything for this?

Comment: @sdasdadas no more than the link in my above comment.